# Openfire plugin integration

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I am developing openfire plugin and facing some performance issues.
My question is which type of plugin integration is fastest.

- PacketInterceptor
- IQHandler
- Component
- Other?

i am using packet interceptor and thinking about switching to IQHandler and send messages via $iq (not $msg). Is it OK to use $iq for sending messages?

Current performance problem is after some time openfire responds very slowly (after 10-20 seconds), i have pubsub module started.

After some observations i found that server dramatically slows if big messages are transferred ( html templates or big json string )

Comment: Have you tried profiling to see where your performance issues are?  What do you consider to be a big message?  Maybe you should explain what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am sending html pages to clients.
After research i've found that i cannot send big messages via xmpp. So first solution is to send as byte stream as chunks and second solution is to redesign architecture of application :).

Comment: Finally after some performance tuning i've found that it is NOT server becomes slow but client side (strophe or browser, i do not know exactly)

Comment: @DidarBurmaganov Can you please help me how to integrate the server to the client side after installing it on the openfire server. Please

Comment: @GauravArora what you want to do? Do you have openfire server and other java server? What you mean by "integrate server to client side"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation i found that html files and other "big" json is not big actually.
Problem is related with browser. Browser limits connections so it slows down on client side.
For testing purposes i used different browsers at same time (chrome, firefox, safari)